# Prove theorem about the last element of a list

Tags: coq

I’ve two functions `build_goal_aux` and `last` defined like this:

```
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

Fixpoint build_goal_aux (acc:list nat)(n:nat) : list nat :=
  match n with
  | O => acc
  | S n' => build_goal_aux (n::acc) n'
  end.

Fixpoint last (l:list nat) : option nat :=
  match l with
    | [] => None
    | a :: [] => Some a
    | _ :: l => last l
  end.
```

I would to prove some theorem about `build_goal_aux`, such as:

```
Lemma build_goal_aux_last : forall n e, last (build_goal_aux [e] n) = Some e.
Lemma build_goal_aux_never_nil : forall (n:nat), build_goal_aux [0] n <> [].
```

But I have no clues about how to do it. I tried an induction on `n`, but I don’t know how to finish the proof. I still want to try to prove it myself, so I don’t want a complete solution, but some clues would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your lemmas are too specific. Let's see what happens when we try to do induction:

```
Lemma build_goal_aux_last : forall n e, last (build_goal_aux [e] n) = Some e.
Proof.
  intros n.
  induction n.
  - easy.
  - intros e.
    simpl.
    (*
      n : nat
      IHn : forall e : nat, last (build_goal_aux [e] n) = Some e
      e : nat
      ============================
      last (build_goal_aux [S n; e] n) = Some e
    *)
Abort.
```

We see that our induction hypothesis talks about `build_goal_aux [e] n` and our goal talks about `build_goal_aux [S n; e] n`, so there is no way that the induction hypothesis is going to be useful. The way out is to generalize the lemma so that it holds for every list given to `build_goal_aux`, and then derive your desired result as a corollary.

What does the lemma try to say? That as long as the `aux` list is non-empty, the last element of `build_goal_aux aux n` is already predetermined regardless of `n`. One way to write this is:

```
Lemma build_goal_aux_last : forall n e w,
  last (build_goal_aux (e :: w) n) = last (e :: w).
```

(Note that I chose to implement "`aux` is non-empty" as `e :: w` instead of as `aux <> []`, which is ultimately a design choice. I prefer this version but YMMV.)

Now the induction hypothesis is actually useful, and your original lemma is obviously a corollary.

The problem with your second lemma is the same and has a similar solution.

This pattern of generalizing a lemma in order to make it provable by induction pops up a lot when you have a recursive definition decreasing on something (a `nat` in this case) that modifies some other argument of the function (a `list nat` in this case). You typically need statements that are fully general in the non-decreasing arguments in order to obtain strong-enough induction hypotheses.